# Extending Scapy Protocols

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to add a new custom protocol layer to Scapy and am encountering a few issues with fields.

I have added a X6BytesField field as follows:

```
class X6BytesField(XByteField):
  def __init__(self, name, default):
    Field.__init__(self, name, default, "!Q")

  def addfield(self, pkt, s, val):    
    return s+struct.pack(self.fmt, self.i2m(pkt,val))[2:8] 

  def getfield(self, pkt, s): 
    return s[2:], self.m2i(pkt, struct.unpack(self.fmt, "\x00\x00"+s[2:])[0])
```

This seems to work ok (hexdump shows the 6 bytes appearing in the right place at least). Now I need to add a 32 Byte field to store a sha256 hash of the packet. What is the best Field to use to store this? I'd prefer to show it as a list of bytes but I've not worked out a way to do that yet. I wondered whether I could use a Python bytearray or a StrFixedLenField?

Another problem I've come across is trying to auto-calculate the sha on the packet (using Python hashlib.sha256()). I've added the following method to the protocol class:

```
def post_build(self, p, pay):    
  if self.sha_hash is None:
    self.sha_hash=calculate_sha(p)      
    l = len(p) - len(self.sha_hash)
    p = p[:l]+struct.pack("!s", self.sha_hash)
  return p + pay
```

Where,

```
def calculate_sha(data):
  return sha256(data).hexdigest()
```

The hash doesn't seem to be calculated though when I use str() to create the packet (obviously missing something here :( ).

I hope there is some Scapy guru out there who can set me on the right track :)